# How to force an item after floats to the next line

Tags: css

I have some code like:

```
<div>First</div>
<div class="second">Second</div>

<a>Alink</a>

div{
    display: block;
float:left;
}

.second{
    clear:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cg4gj/

I really want the link though to be on the next line down. Currently it is positioned beside second. How do I force elements after these floats to go to the next line. I definitely do NOT want to make the divs take up the entire width of the page though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add display : block to the a tag and clear:both
http://jsfiddle.net/cg4gj/3/

Comment: thanks that works but is there a way to do it just modifying the div tags incase I make this part of a reusable bit of markup and place somewhere else?

Comment: @AnonyMouse you can surround with divs with parent tag and set its css to overflow:auto;
http://jsfiddle.net/cg4gj/11/ or look at Musa's answer

Comment: Cool, I like the overflow: auto way.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitely define float:left just for the first div

http://jsfiddle.net/cg4gj/9/

Comment: close but the divs take up the entire width of the line. ie. The second fills the rest of the line. This isn't going to work because I was wanting to put a border around and if it runs the width of the page it will look uneven.